# How can I fix emoji printing issues in PHP?

Tags: php, svg

I'm currently developing an emoji list for a chat. Because some emojis have display problems, I had the idea to convert the emojis to e.g. SVG's before I output them. My list has a lots of entries like this:

```
    $test = [
    [
        'id'    => 'couple-heart',
        'name'  => 'Couple with heart',
        'emoji' => ''
    ],
    [
        'id'    => 'grinning-face-big-eyes',
        'name'  => 'Grinning face with big eyes',
        'emoji' => ''
    ]
];

foreach ( $test as $item ) {
    echo $item['emoji'];
}
```

One example for my printing issue is:

```
☹
```

Which should be:

[image: php]

Maybe my file encoding is a problem? Currently it's `UTF-8` but this should normally be fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Emojis are just special characters, which font do you have where the emoji looks like the image you are expecting it to be?

Comment: I'm using Open Sans on my page. Could this be a problem? I thought emojis are part of the system (Chrome, Mac, Windows). The image shows the emoji from WhatsApp and this is also the expected result. A lot's of emojis works but to many have problems like shown above.

Comment: I would assume so. You should find out which ones are in your font and which ones are not. Or create a font where all the ones you need are in. Not sure about fallback mechanisms with fonts so it might be possible your browser falls back to other fonts if NONE of the emojis are in the font you actually use

Comment: @ArSeN Thanks for the hint! It looks like that it's only the font. Damn. Do you have any idea which font is the correct one? And whats about my chat input? I want to keep my page font here but what if someone enters a "problematic emoji"?

Comment: I do not think there is a "correct one". Each font is basically a definition of "which pixels to show inside a small box for which number", and emojis are no different. Find a font that you want to use (and contains the emojis you want to use) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try converting using the javascript codePointAt() and display it on the client side using javascript fromCodePoint().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Unicode data file: [emoji-test.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.0/emoji-test.txt), ☹ <U+2639> is an "unqualified" (or "non-fully-qualified") emoji sequence, and may be displayed as text or as emoji depending on the environment (operating system, fonts available, etc.)
To be on the safe side, always use the "fully-qualified" emoji sequence; here, that would be: ☹️ <U+2639, U+FE0F>

Comment: If I use the fully-qualified icon like "&#9785; &#65039;️" (HTML entity), there is still the text emoji printed. I don't understand this.

Comment: Try "&#9785;&#65039;" without a space inserted between the two HTML entities...

Answer (score 0):

As a previous contributor pointed out, you likely have an unqualified (i.e. incomplete) emoji.  The Unicode standard defines numbers (a.k.a. "code points") for virtually every character we know, including emojis.  A font's job is to display a small image corresponding to each code point (so your idea to convert characters into images is basically re-inventing a wheel).

However, some emojis are represented by *multiple* code points.
For example, the single displayed character  is a grapheme, composed of **two** code points: U+1F1FA and U+1F1F8.  To make things even more confusing, some emojis are sometimes represented as a single code point, and other times they are represented by a combination of graphemes (I think the emoji for "family" falls into this category).  In any case, if you're dealing with a scenario where you've got an incomplete emoji sequence, then different fonts or operating systems or browsers or apps (???) may behave differently, and some may fail more gracefully than others.

It may be helpful for you to check whether or not the given character(s) are valid code points.  PHP can be compiled with the [Multibyte String extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) -- it offers a few functions that may be helpful for this, e.g. [mb_check_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) and [mb_ord](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php) (`mb_ord` is unfortunately not documented (!!!) but it will give you the code point of the first character in the given string).  PHP may not have the best support for strings out there, but it should be able to do what you need.

Hope this helps!